# unable to login to the wso2 IS-KM 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 ID server as KM 5.10.0 with API manager 3.1.0 . This is very basic issue. In my previous attempts I was able to login to the Wso2 Id server. But by mistake I started two instances of the ID server. After that I killed both the processes which are running and tried starting only one instance. after that I am unable to login to the wso2 ID server. I tried restarting whole linux system and try to login but still I am getting the below exception.

```
[2020-06-23 12:02:43,999] [50882c23-5ee1-4406-ae80-0a688cb89a4e] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve} - Could not handle request: /carbon java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.Utils.getAppNameFromRequest(Utils.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.initCarbonContext(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try to login with a different browser or the incognito mode?

Comment: Thanks, with different browser it worked. Why such exception?

Comment: A similar issue is raised here https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6755